# TCP Server throughput slows down

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener, throughput

I am trying to develop some small app to measure Wi-Fi Throughput. I have this code so far:

```
private void handle_connection(IAsyncResult result) 
    {
        accept_connection();  
        client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);  
        long total = 0;
        double start = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
        while ((flag))
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1024 * 100];

                ns.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                total += bytesFrom.Length;
                double cost = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds - start;
                double megaBytes = (total / (1024.0 * 1024));
                double seconds = Convert.ToDouble((cost / 1000.0).ToString("0.00"));
                float MB_Result = Convert.ToSingle((megaBytes / seconds).ToString("0.00"));
                float Mbit_Result = MB_Result * 8;

                Invoke(new System.Action(() => chart.Series["Mbps"].Points.AddXY(seconds, Mbit_Result)));
                Invoke(new System.Action(() => currSpeedLbl.Text = Mbit_Result + " Mbit/s (" + MB_Result + "MB/s)"));

            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
            }
        }


    }
```

I try to show my results on the graph. At the begging of the transmission I have some 60Mbit/s of speed, but after a while it falls down to 1Mbit. I am very new to network programming, so it is possible I did something terribly stupid. Can I ask for some suggestions? Thank you

Comment: For starters, stop ignoring exceptions.. You question is like "oohh, I don't want to see the exceptions but something is wrong. tell me what so I don't have too read those exceptions"

Comment: You are ignoring the result of `ns.Read`. Common mistake.; Do not run blocking code on the UI thread. Move this work to a Task for example.

Comment: It works on other thread at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

You set start at the beginning and don't update it during the course of the application. The first iteration is measured against (now - start) which will be a relatively quick time. Your later iterations will be measured against  (now - start) which is a greater amount of time than the previous call. To accurately measure throughput I think you need to move setting the start time to inside your loop, but before your read.

Comment: Also, don't reallocate the buffer on every time through the loop. And note that `ReceiveBufferSize` isn't 100KB and thus isn't equal to the size of the buffer you actually allocated.